# When should animation animate when scrolling?

Tags: usability, scrolling, animation

I like using animations that happen whilst visitors are scrolling down my site. In order to do this, I need to set a height for at what stage of how far down they have scrolled, to create an action to start this animation.

Currently I make it occur about 2-300px above the element to animate. I am not sure if this is really the best. Is there a set practice? 
E.g. I was thinking perhaps it should be as soon as the full animation container is in view, which is a bit harder to code. Also would likely need something different for responsive.

Can anyone suggest at what stage of scrolling should an animation begin whilst moving down the page?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html
It's a .js library that works together with animate.css

Animation starts when user scrolls to the animated element. For me it's an easy solution, also works smooth.